# Not able to apply update cursor on OS MasterMap feature classes created using OS Translator II

Tags: arcpy, cursor, feature-class, os-mastermap

I am using OS Translator tool to convert OSMasterMap GZ files to PostgreSQL database. The feature classes created are query layers and cannot be edited in ArcGIS.
Now I am writing a code to add new data to the existing feature classes. For this purpose, I am deleting the old rows in the given extent of new data and inserting the new data.
However, I am getting an error "Create cursor failed" while deleting and I haven't even tried Inserting.

What I have done as an alternative workaround is that :

1. I created shapefiles of the OS Master Map feature classes locally.
2. Then I created new feature classes in PostgreSQL with similar fields which is for some reason editable.
3. I am then trying to insert the data from shapefile to this new editable feature class.

After this I am able to update and insert data on the new feature class when new data comes.

Please can you tell me if I can directly update and insert the feature classes created by OS Translator so that I can skip these steps in the middle.

Here is my code:

```
import arcpy
import datetime

temp_workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
sde_workspace = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
arcpy.env.workspace = sde_workspace

try:

  #Converting Feature Classes to Shapefiles in Temporary workspace
        arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion(["postgretest.postgres.boundaryline","postgretest.postgres.cartographicsymbol","postgretest.postgres.cartographictext", "postgretest.postgres.topographicarea", "postgretest.postgres.topographicline","postgretest.postgres.topographicpoint"], temp_workspace)

#Looping through each shapefile and updating the features in featuredataset in enterprise geodatabase
arcpy.env.workspace = temp_workspace
fcList = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

for fc in fcList:

    #Boundary Line............................................................................
    if(fc == "boundaryline.shp"):
        fc1 = fc
        fc2 = sde_workspace + "\postgretest.postgres.boundary_line"

        print "Starting for Boundary Line..."

        #set up cursor for adding features
        inscursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(fc2,["postgretest.postgres.boundary_line.fid","FEATURECODE","VERSION","versiondate","accuracyofposition","make","physicallevel","physicalpresence","style_description","style_code","SHAPE@"])
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc1,["fid_","featurecod","version","versiondat","accuracyof","make","physicalle","physicalpr","style_desc","style_code","SHAPE@"]) as innercursor:
            for searchrow in innercursor:
                geom = searchrow[10]
                row_values = [searchrow[0], int(searchrow[1]),int(searchrow[2]), searchrow[3],int(searchrow[4]),int(searchrow[5]),int(searchrow[6]),searchrow[7],searchrow[8], int(searchrow[9]),geom]
                inscursor.insertRow(row_values)

        del(innercursor)
        del(inscursor)
        arcpy.Delete_management(fc1)
```

Source Table:
"wkb_geometry" - Geometry
"fid" - Text Length = 0
"featurecode" - Long Numeric
"version" - Long Numeric
"versiondate" - Text Length = 0
"accuracyofposition" - Text
"make" - Text
"physicallevel" Numeric Long
"physicalpresence" - Text
"style_description" - Text
"style_code" - Nummeric Long

Comment: A description of the as-built tables would be far more useful than work-around code. ArcGIS doesn't support BIGINT datatypes, so if the tables contain one, that's your issue.

Comment: Hi Vince, I am not too confident if there is a BIGINT column because there were some columns added while converting the gz files which gave an error invalid column upon adding in Arcmap and I have removed those columns now while converting to featureclass and still the layer is not editable. Please can you elaborate a little bit on the as-built table approach.

Comment: I have found a field style_description which is of length 1073741822. Could this be the cause???

Comment: As-built isn't an approach, so it can't be elaborated.  You need to describe the source table *in the question* so that your cursor issue can be understood.  There is nothing wrong with having a CLOB column in a table. Looking at your code, it appears you're playing fast and loose with login/user/schema (and using postgres -- a ***HUGE*** security no-no) which could mess up any write access

Comment: Hi Vince, sure I will keep in mind to have a new user and a new schema. This is a test scenario where the final aim is to maintain the National Master Map database.

Comment: I have added source table description

Comment: Also, if it helps when I go to data source, Data Type of the layer comes as Query Feature Class.

Comment: Hi Vince, So I have created a new Enterprise Database and followed the instruction given in this link . I have also created a new user role called testuser. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/gdbs-in-postgresql/get-started-gdb-in-postgresql.htm. However, Now when I go to QGIS and try connecting to PostGIS database using testuser credentials, it says connection failed. THere is an entry for all users in pg_hba file so it should ideally work??

Comment: Hi Vince, I am able to connect through QGIS the testuser schema. Now when I apply OS Translator Tool and create feature clasees. They are still uneditable.